ILGPU kernel runs significantly slower on Nvidia than on AMD GPU
I am currently exploring the possibilities of parallelized GPU calculations for our company. As we by far mainly work in the .NET context, my first approach was taking a look at the ILGPU framework. I worked through the tutorials on the ILGPU website and wrote a proof of concept programme with a simple benchmarking function.
This programme allows the user to run geometric operations on a selectable number of geometric points using the different accelerators ILGPU offers. In the case of my work laptop, these are CPU Accelerator, integrated Graphics accelerator and Nvidia RTX A2000 accelerator. The operations can also be performed using sequential and parallel (implemented with Parallel.For()) processing on the CPU. Afterwards, you can compare the time these operations take.
Now, after a bit of testing on different hardware, it looks as though my C#-ILGPU-code works significantly slower on Nvidia GPUs than on AMD ones. More precisely, on the Nvidia hardware we tested, running the programme on the GPU took much longer than running it in parallel on the CPU, even though the parallel-processing of millions of geometric points suggests the GPU should have a great advantage here. This phenomenon also occurs on the pretty strong Nvidia RTX 4080 of my colleague's private computer.
On my private PC which works with a Ryzen 5 5600X and AMD RX 6800 XT on the other hand, the programme works as expected and performs much better on the GPU than in parallel on the CPU.
Obviously, the difference is that ILGPU uses OpenCL for AMD GPUs while using CUDA with Nvidia GPUs. So my thought is that I'm just missing some optimization feature or something in order to use CUDAs maximum power.
I would greatly appreciate any suggestions in this matter.
Below you can find the relevant bits of my ILGPU code:
// Parallel auf GPU
public void processOnGPU()
{
    // Beschleuniger prüfen und benötigte Daten übertragen
    if (selectedAccelerator == null)
    {
        throw new NullReferenceException("No accelerator set for calculation.");
    }

    liPtRequestOnDevice = selectedAccelerator.Allocate1D(liPtRequest);
    polyOnDevice = selectedAccelerator.Allocate1D(poly);
    bReturnOnDevice = selectedAccelerator.Allocate1D(bReturn);
    index = (int)liPtRequestOnDevice.Length;

    // GPU-Kernel initialisieren und ausführen
    Action<Index1D, ArrayView<PointXY>, ArrayView<PointXY>, ArrayView<byte>> loadedKernel = selectedAccelerator.LoadAutoGroupedStreamKernel<Index1D, ArrayView<PointXY>, ArrayView<PointXY>, ArrayView<byte>>(GPUKernelAutoGroupSize);

    // GPU-Kernel ausführen
    loadedKernel(index, liPtRequestOnDevice.View, polyOnDevice.View, bReturnOnDevice.View);

    // ggf. kompilierten Kernel zurückgeben
    if (bReturnCompiledKernel && !string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(strReturnKernelFilepath))
    {
        var kernel = loadedKernel.GetCompiledKernel() as PTXCompiledKernel;
        if (kernel != null)
        {
            writeTextToFile(kernel.PTXAssembly, strReturnKernelFilepath);
        }
    }

    // auf Beendigung der Aufgabe warten
    selectedAccelerator.Synchronize();

    // Rückgabe setzen
    if (callback != null)
    {
        bReturn = bReturnOnDevice.GetAsArray1D();
        bool[] bReturnBool = new bool[bReturn.Length];

        for (int i = 0; i < bReturn.Length; i++)
        {
            if (bReturn[i] == 1)
            {
                bReturnBool[i] = true;
            } else
            {
                bReturnBool[i] = false;
            }
        }

        callback(bReturnBool);
    }

    // genutzten Speicher kontrolliert freigeben
    cleanup();
}

// Parallel auf GPU
private static void GPUKernelAutoGroupSize(Index1D i, ArrayView<PointXY> arrPtRequest, ArrayView<PointXY> arrPtPoly, ArrayView<byte> output)
{            
    if (ptInPolyGPU(arrPtRequest[i], arrPtPoly))
    {
        output[i] = 1;
    } else
    {
        output[i] = 0;
    }
}

Update:
As requested in the comments, here are a few words concerning my benchmarking code. The whole programme is designed as a Windows Forms application. In order to be able to measure the time running the algorithms is taking, I'm starting the calculations as a separate thread like so:
PointXY[] liPtPoly = poly.points.ToArray();

// Klasse für Ausführungsthread entsprechend Hardware-Auswahl nutzen
if (cmbAccelerators.SelectedItem == DEV_CPU_PARALLEL || cmbAccelerators.SelectedItem == DEV_CPU_SEQUENTIAL)
{
    var cpuCalculation = new PtInPolyCalculationAsync(liPtRequest.ToArray(), liPtPoly, ResultCallback);
    cpuCalculation.setProcessParallelly(cmbAccelerators.SelectedItem == DEV_CPU_PARALLEL);
    calcThread = new Thread(new ThreadStart(cpuCalculation.processOnCPU));
}
else
{
    bool bGetCompiledKernel = chkSaveKernel.Enabled && chkSaveKernel.Checked;
    var gpuCalculation = new PtInPolyCalculationAsync(liPtRequest.ToArray(), liPtPoly, ResultCallback);
    gpuCalculation.setSelectedAccelerator(selectedAccelerator);
    gpuCalculation.setUseCustomBlockSize(true);
    if (chkSaveKernel.Checked)
    {
        gpuCalculation.setReturnCompiledKernel(true, txtFilepath.Text);
    }
    calcThread = new Thread(new ThreadStart(gpuCalculation.processOnGPU));
}

timeElapsed = 0;
bCallbackCalled = false;
tmrStopwatch.Start();

calcThread.Start();

For the actual time measuring I use a simple Windows Forms Timer which is set to a 100 ms interval, so I'm basically measuring 10ths of seconds. I am, of course, aware that this is a really rough way of measuring time for benchmarking purposes. Therefore, I am running the calculations for 5,000,000 to 500,000,000 geometrical points (depending on the hardware) in order to be able to perceive a trend nevertheless.
Following, you can see what said timer is doing:
private void tmrStopwatch_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    timeElapsed += 1;
    if (calcThread != null)
    {
        if (!calcThread.IsAlive || bCallbackCalled)
        {
            tmrStopwatch.Stop();
            calcThread = null;
            setActivateControls();
        }
        else
        {
            tsStatus.Text = calcThread.ThreadState.ToString() + " - " + (timeElapsed / (1000 / tmrStopwatch.Interval)).ToString() + " Sekunden";
        }
    }
}

In the following screenshots you can see the results of a few measurements (status strip, lower end of the window).



Hardware
Points
Polygon-Vertices
Time [s]




AMD Ryzen 5 5600X, using Parallel.For()
500,000,000
18
45.1


AMD RX 6800 XT
500,000,000
18
5.7


Intel i7-11800H, using Parallel.For()
5,000,000
4
0.6


Nvidia RTX A2000 (mobile)
5,000,000
4
2.2


Intel i9-11900K, using Parallel.For()
500,000,000
40
~80


Nvidia RTX 4080
500,000,000
40
~300



Results from my work laptop use less points of test data and a polygon with less vertices due to the lesser performance of the hardware.
Also, I just noticed that it does not in fact take the GPU take 10 times more time to process the tasks like I said earlier. Still, I think the tendency is obvious.

Did you install the proprietary Nvidia drivers? If you're using Linux, you have to do this yourself as they don't come pre-installed. Please provide details of your OS.

Nvidia GPUs can also use OpenCL if the API lets you choose that. I don;t know ILGPU but you could look into trying to run it as OpenCL on your Nvidia GPUs.

We're working in a Windows-only environment, myself using Windows 10, some of my colleagues already upgraded to Windows 11. The only thing I did was installing the ILGPU package and the ILGPU Algorithms package from the NuGet packet manager. I understood this was enough.
The proprietary drivers have been installed though, I'm currently on version 561.17. However, I just noticed that the Nvidia Control Panel isn't started automatically on my computer. I don't suppose this has anything to do with the problem though, right?

As far as I am aware, ILGPU automatically chooses which API to use, using CUDA with Nvidia GPUs and OpenCL for anything else. If it were indeed using OpenCL with our Nvidia GPUs instead of OpenCL though, this could possibly explain the unexpectedly-low performance...

Is it possible that your benchmarking is too naive and you are measuring overheads? Are you invoking the kernel multiple times and ideally throwing away the first (few) iteration(s)? Please include the benchmarking code.

It would be prudent to confirm if it runs on the Nvidia GPU at all (vs some sequential CPU fallback).

@paleonix: Well, the benachmarking code is by all means simple and does intentionally include the overhead of memory operations. Still, on my AMD GPU the algorithm runs almost 10 times faster than in parallel on the CPU. On the tested Nvidia devices it runs more like 10 times slower on GPU than on CPU. I don't suppose this much of a difference results merely from inaccurate performance measuring.
How would I confirm that the code actually gets executed on the GPU? This sounds like an interesting approach.

We need to see the benchmarking code and results. GPUs are good for high throughput high latency applications. If you're measuring microsecond scale performance, you could get wild variations.

There is not only the memory overhead (which is important to mention) but also others that might depend on the backend (lazy loading of GPU modules, driver, context creation, hardware power states). So even when you are benchmarking memory transfers + computation, the first iteration/launch is rarely very informative (assuming your real-world application will run it's kernel(s) more than once.

I'm on Linux but I would think that Windows Task Manager should show activity on the GPU when a kernel is running.

I added the requested code and further information to the OP. Thank you for your interest so far! You are right that ILGPU caches compiled kernels and re-uses them if possible. However, running the benchmarks again only changed the results insignificantly.
The Taskmanager does indeed show gfx activity. However, so far I don't find the displays very conclusive. I'm assuming I'm using it wrong. While Visual Studio profiler states the GPU is being used, Taskmanager most the time doesn't.

Note that a mobile A2000 is a pretty weak GPU not only in terms of compute but also in terms of memory bandwidth which is often the bottleneck for GPGPU workloads outside dense matrix-matrix products. It seems to have a bandwidth of only 192.0 GB/s. This is still much higher than the i7 I think, but in combination with the data transfer it is a performance killer as PCIe bandwidth is even lower. You can use Nsight Systems (Nvidias Tracing application; comes with the CUDA Toolkit) to check how much time is spent on computation vs memory transfer.

That is true. Still, the tendency was also observable for my colleague's RTX 4080. I'm adding his test results to the OP.

Thank you for making my OP better readable, @paleonix! Btw., I'm parallely working on a similar programme in C++, working directly with the CUDA Toolkit. When leaving the time needed for transfering the needed data to the GPU out of the equation, the CUDA version is 2.5 times faster than the CPU Parallel.For() version. When included, CUDA takes twice the time of the CPU. Taskmanager here also basically only shows activity for the GPU memory, not the GPU ALUs.

If data transfer from and to the GPU for every launch is really needed, you will need pipelining to get reasonable performance if at all. See How to Overlap Data Transfers in CUDA C/C++ (Nvidia Developer Blog). Not sure if this tractable in C# though. It would also be interesting how this issue is avoided on the AMD card with OpenCL.

When each address is touched (read or written) only once by the GPU, another option is to directly read/write to pinned host memory in the kernel to overlap transfer and computation. Again, no idea if this is possible in C#.

I read that OpenCL does indeed support pipelining. If this really is the bottleneck, I'll need to think in a different direction. Maybe transferring larger amounts of data in small chunks while letting the GPU already start calculating would be a way. What do you mean by your second point, "directly read/write to pinned host memory"?

See CUDA C++ Best Practices Guide: Memory Optimizations: Data Transfer Between Host and Device, especially the "Zero Copy" section.

Thanks for the hints. "Staged concurrent copy and execute" seems to describe what I was thinking of, transferring the data in chunks and meanwhiles already starting to execute the calculations. I suppose your links provide me with a couple of new ideas to take in.
